# Kodi and SNES30 (bluetooth) not working

Tags: bluetooth, kodi, retropie, joystick

I've got retropie 3.8 installed with kodi running

I've installed kodi via:

1. **sudo apt-get update**
2. **sudo apt-get install kodi** (currently 15.2)
3. identified controller via **cat /proc/bus/input/devices**
   (8BitDo SNES30 GamePad)
4. defined new **joystick.xml** under **/home/pi/.kodi/userdata/keymaps/** with the same name and basic mappings e.g.

```xml
<keymap>
<global>
    <joystick name="8BitDo SNES30 GamePad">
    <button id="1">Select</button>
    <button id="0">Back</button>
    <axis id="1" limit="-1">Up</axis>
    <axis id="1" limit="+1">Down</axis>
    <axis id="2" limit="-1">Left</axis>
    <axis id="2" limit="+1">Right</axis>
  </joystick>
</global>
</keymap>
```

5. start Kodi (**sudo kodi**)
6. Joystick isn't registered

If I look at the **kodi.log** under **/home/pi/.kodi/temp/** I can see that *SNES30* is attempting to be mapped via **dev/input/event3** which is not right (it should be **js0**)

Comment: Rather than using **cat /proc/bus/input/devices** you can simply run **evtest** and then select your registered device - very useful for testing the buttons work etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: I've almost got it working. It turns out that v3.8 of retropie (with upgraded settings) only includes 15.2 of Kodi **with joysticks not compiled in it**. Current apt-get didn't have any newer versions of Kodi and so I:

1. Add experimental repository of Kodi for raspbian (currently 16.1)

**echo 'deb http://pipplware.pplware.pt/pipplware/dists/jessie/main/binary /' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipplware_jessie.list**

2. Add repository key

**wget -O - http://pipplware.pplware.pt/pipplware/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -**

3. Update apt-get

**sudo apt-get update**

4. Uninstall old kodi

**sudo apt-get remove kodi**

5. Install new kodi

**sudo apt-get install kodi**

This rendition of kodi includes joystick support. the joystick map mostly works although *the next conundrum* is that **only left/down** currently works even though *it should* work - the other button mappings work fine, though.

Comment: It seems that 16.1 is also buggy. Kodi 17 will be delivering more robust support for joysticks and gamepads http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Configure_controllers